# Excel. How can I prevent Excel from returning an error while filtering an empty pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

So basically as the question speaks for itself, im trynna filter an empty pivot table (table is getting data from a sql query so sometimes it can be empty). Excel in return gives me #ARG error back but i wanna catch it.

My table:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbe7H.png)

Things I tried:
`=FILTER(NaleznosciPLN,(NOT(ISBLANK(NaleznosciPLN)))*(DATEVALUE(NaleznosciPLN[TerminPlatnosci])>=DATEVALUE("01.01.2022")); 0)` - This still returns an #ARG

Also:
`=SUM(IF(ISBLANK(NaleznosciPLN);0;FILTER(NaleznosciPLN;(DATEVALUE(NaleznosciPLN[TerminPlatnosci])>=DATAVALUE("16.07.2022"))*(DATAVALUE(NaleznosciPLN[TerminPlatnosci])<DATEVALUE("01.12.2022")); 0)))`

The second one works just fine as long as data doesn't have multiple records. What i mean by this? I noticed that Excel takes the first value which matches the condition and then multiplies it by the total rows count, I don't know how to excatly describe it but I hope u'll understand what I mean xd [Image showing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXvKn.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce the results or problem on my machine, but it would seem that you could do:

```
=SUM( (NaleznosciPLN[TerminPlatnosci] >= DATEVALUE( "16.07.2022") ) *
      (NaleznosciPLN[TerminPlatnosci] < DATEVALUE( "31.12.2022") ) *
       NaleznosciPLN[Suma] )
```

Comment: sadly, this doesn't work for me, it's returning me a 0 :/ But thanks for replying!